# Android Spinner from server

Tags: android, json, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

i have a spinner in my apps. that spinner will be filled some data from server. in my logcat, i was successfully parse JSON data but i don't why when i tried setting up the adapter i got `java.lang.NullPointerException` error and this is my log :

```
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:47)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:169)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:125)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at com.example.androidsql.NewProductActivity$getCity$1.run(NewProductActivity.java:437)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:3743)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at com.example.androidsql.NewProductActivity$getCity.onPostExecute(NewProductActivity.java:433)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at com.example.androidsql.NewProductActivity$getCity.onPostExecute(NewProductActivity.java:1)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
10-31 04:59:01.607: E/AndroidRuntime(28692):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is my java class :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_product);
        ctx = this;

        //define all input text
        longitude = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_longitude);
        latitude = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_latitude);
        merchant = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_merchant);
        alamat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_alamat);
        telp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_telpon);
        hp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_hape);
        bb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_bb);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email);

        //spinner
        spinCategory = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin_category);

        dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);

        new getCity().execute();

        spinCategoryDetail = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin_category_detail);

        //define path directory
        et_uploadlogo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_path_uploadlogo);
        et_uploadfoto_f = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_path_uploadfoto_f);
        et_uploadfoto_s = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_path_uploadfoto_s);

        //define image
        img_logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview_logo);
        img_foto_f = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview_foto_f);
        img_foto_s = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview_foto_s);

        //OK button
        imgbtn_ok = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_ok);
        //refresh button
        btn_refresh = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_refreshlonglat);

        //button browse
        btn_browse_ulogo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_browse_uploadlogo);
        btn_browse_ufoto_f = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_browse_uploadfoto_f);
        btn_browse_ufoto_s = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_browse_uploadfoto_s);

        //location service
        locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1, 1000, this.locationListener);

        //get CurretLocation
        showCurrentLocation();

        //action click buttton browse image logo
        btn_browse_ulogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent ig = new Intent();
                    ig.setType("image/*");
                    ig.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(ig, "Select Picture"), IMAGE_GALLERY_LOGO);
            }
        });

      //action click buttton browse image foto1
        btn_browse_ufoto_f.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent ig = new Intent();
                ig.setType("image/*");
                ig.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(ig, "Select Picture"), IMAGE_GALLERY_FOTO_F);
            }
        });

      //action click buttton browse image foto2
        btn_browse_ufoto_s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent ig = new Intent();
                ig.setType("image/*");
                ig.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(ig, "Select Picture"), IMAGE_GALLERY_FOTO_S);
            }
        });

      //refresh longitude,latitude
        btn_refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCurrentLocation();
            }
        });

        imgbtn_ok = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_ok);
        imgbtn_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //post data
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_GALLERY_LOGO) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                fileUri_logo = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(fileUri_logo);
                et_uploadlogo.setText(selectedImagePath); 
                img_logo.setImageURI(fileUri_logo);
            }   
        } else {
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_GALLERY_FOTO_F) {
                fileUri_foto_f = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(fileUri_foto_f);
                et_uploadfoto_f.setText(selectedImagePath);
                img_foto_f.setImageURI(fileUri_foto_f);
            } else {
                if (requestCode == IMAGE_GALLERY_FOTO_S) {
                    fileUri_foto_s = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(fileUri_foto_s);
                    et_uploadfoto_s.setText(selectedImagePath);
                    img_foto_s.setImageURI(fileUri_foto_s);
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    protected void showCurrentLocation() {
        Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            String lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
            latitude.setText(lat);
            longitude.setText(lon);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading, saving data...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating data
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            slongitude = longitude.getText().toString();
            slatitude = latitude.getText().toString();
            smerchant = merchant.getText().toString();
            salamat = alamat.getText().toString();
            stelp = telp.getText().toString();
            shp = hp.getText().toString();
            sbb = bb.getText().toString();
            semail = email.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pk_Merchant_ID", ""));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Fk_Ms_DataLevel2_ID", "2"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Fk_Ms_City_ID", "2"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Fk_Ms_Sales_ID_CreatedBy", "1"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FK_Ms_Sales_ID_LastUpdateBy", "1"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CreatedDated", ""));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LastUpdateDated", ""));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("merchant", smerchant));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alamat", salamat));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telp", stelp));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hp", shp));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bb", sbb));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", semail));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", slongitude));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", slatitude));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Is_Deleted", ""));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_merchant,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Log.d("Berhasil", "Good");

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PreviewActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("lon", slongitude);
                        i.putExtra("lat", slatitude);
                        i.putExtra("mer", smerchant);
                        i.putExtra("ala", salamat);
                        i.putExtra("tel", stelp);
                        i.putExtra("hp", shp);
                        i.putExtra("pbb", sbb);
                        i.putExtra("ema", semail);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Gagal", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    class getCity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_spincategory, "GET", param);
            Log.d("Get List Spinner Category :", json.toString());

            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_Ms_DataLevel1);
                    for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject j = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        Pk_Ms_DataLevel1_ID[i] = j.getString(TAG_Pk_Ms_DataLevel1_ID);
                        Descriptions[i] = j.getString(TAG_Descriptions);

                        list_category = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list_category.add(Descriptions[i]);
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Descriptions);
                    dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

i need your advices, comments and all of your helps. thanks for advance.

Comment: best way to find your bug is to add logs before the line that is causing the exception.
and check all the data that you are passing to the adapter if it is null, and also check the view it self if it is not null.

Comment: I agree with @user1597833. It looks like `Descriptions` is null.

Comment: @user1597833 if you don't mind, can you correct my code as your explanation? i really need your helps.

Comment: what is written on line 437 in NewProductActivity.java ?
paste that line.

Comment: '  protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Descriptions);
       dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
  //        dataAdapter1.add(Descriptions);
      }
     });
    }'